# Using multiple ace editor instances with different completers

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

how could I set up individual completers per ace editor instance?

I am using multiple editors in my application.
- setting completers on the languageTools object seems to just add duplicates for all editor instances at once

```
     langTools.addCompleter(myCompleter);
```

- setting completers directly on the editor seems to produce the same result.

  `editor.completers.push(myCompleter);`

(All editors should keep their default completers)

Answer (score 7):

In my second example, the completers were handed by reference, so I was always adding completers to the central list of completers, which ended up in duplicates.

This works:

```
editor.completers = editor.completers.slice();
editor.completers.push(myCompleter);
```